# How can I track down the standard TeX glyphs for musical accidentals ($\flat$, etc.)?

Tags: symbols, computer-modern

I'm trying to determine how to import the standard TeX music accidental glyphs into LilyPond (\flat, \sharp, and \natural), but I'm having trouble tracking down the specific glyphs. Are they from Computer Modern? I'm not able to find them in any Computer Modern glyph collections. Nor do these glyphs seem to align with the standard Unicode characters.

Where are these glyphs from, and how can I locate/isolate them on my machine?

Comment: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en page 163

Comment: of course Lilypond has its own syntax and glyphs for accidentals, so why exactly do you need to find the LaTeX versions of these glyphs?

Comment: @Marijn I'm aiming for some more consistency between the text and score annotations, that's all. I'm hoping there's a way I can use the LaTeX versions only for annotations, and not in the actual music notation itself.

Answer (score 1):

Computer Modern predates Unicode by quite a bit (it actually predates 8-bit text encodings as well). The symbol tables that John Kormylo linked to are a decent starting point although they're perhaps a bit *too* comprehensive as they contain huge numbers of optional fonts.

Knuth stashed the symbols for flat, natural and sharp into the math italic fonts (`cmmi*`) in the character codes for `[` `\` and `]` respectively (hex 5B–5D). *The TeXbook* also contains tables of the font characters.